# compile darknet as dll

Tags: python, yolo, darknet, labelimg

im having some problems with google colab:

when i try to compile darknet with `LIBSO=1`, and `#define TRACK_OPTFLOW` i got this error message:

```
...
In file included from src/yolo_console_dll.cpp:23:0:
include/yolo_v2_class.hpp:233:10: fatal error: opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp: No such file or directory 
#include <opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp>
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:155: recipe for target 'uselib' failed
make: *** [uselib] Error 1
```

then i added the missing .hpp files to a new opencv2 folder inside colab, but I get this other problem,

```
/tmp/ccRQih9B.o: In function `Tracker_optflow::tracking_flow(cv::Mat, bool)':
yolo_console_dll.cpp:(.text._ZN15Tracker_optflow13tracking_flowEN2cv3MatEb[_ZN15Tracker_optflow13tracking_flowEN2cv3MatEb]+0x108): undefined reference to `cv::cuda::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int, cv::cuda::Stream&)'
/tmp/ccRQih9B.o: In function `Tracker_optflow::update_tracking_flow(cv::Mat, std::vector<bbox_t, std::allocator<bbox_t> >)':
yolo_console_dll.cpp:(.text._ZN15Tracker_optflow20update_tracking_flowEN2cv3MatESt6vectorI6bbox_tSaIS3_EE[_ZN15Tracker_optflow20update_tracking_flowEN2cv3MatESt6vectorI6bbox_tSaIS3_EE]+0x2aa): undefined reference to `cv::cuda::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int, cv::cuda::Stream&)'
yolo_console_dll.cpp:(.text._ZN15Tracker_optflow20update_tracking_flowEN2cv3MatESt6vectorI6bbox_tSaIS3_EE[_ZN15Tracker_optflow20update_tracking_flowEN2cv3MatESt6vectorI6bbox_tSaIS3_EE]+0x332): undefined reference to `cv::cuda::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int, cv::cuda::Stream&)'
/tmp/ccRQih9B.o: In function `main':
yolo_console_dll.cpp:(.text.startup+0x7d7): undefined reference to `cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::create(cv::Size_<int>, int, int, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:155: recipe for target 'uselib' failed
make: *** [uselib] Error 1
```

I suppose it's a Colab problem,

Comment: i have a problem too hopefully someone can assist

Comment: teel me, what is the problem?